# synchronization between lyx and pdf preview

Tags: lyx, forward-inverse-search, preview

A feature that I terribly miss in Lyx (compared to standard tex editors), is that when I click on "Preview Pdf" I get exactly to where I'm editing rightnow.

A less missed feature is to go back from the PDF to the editor in a particular point.

Does the first feature exists in Lyx? Maybe also the second?
I use Mac OS.

Comment: both features exist and are called "reverse (or inverse) search" and "forward search". Please search for those terms in Help > Additional Features. I use them regularly with LyX on Ubuntu.

Comment: @scottkosty This should be the answer! I didn't know what this feature was called, so your comment helped. You should write it up and let me upvote. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both features exist and are called "reverse (or inverse) search" and "forward search". Please search for those terms in Help > Additional Features. I use them regularly with LyX on Ubuntu. Setting them up is platform dependent so follow the instructions for your platform. Also note that only certain PDF readers support these features.

Comment: +1! I also found some useful information in the [wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX), some of which was missing in the Help.

Comment: @Sparhawk yes that's good. I hope that we can implement some sort of automatic configuration in the future, as I suggest at [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg195967.html).